# Localhost website not accessible from Public IP despite port forwarding

Tags: web-hosting, localhost, publishing

My tiny office has 1 router, which is connected to ADSL line on one end and my laptop on other end. In office, laptop's local IP is `192.168.1.2`.

On office router, I have setup port (22) forwarding for SSH access. I also have DuckDNS script that allows me to `ssh -v -t -L 5900:localhost:5900 myname.duckdns.org` into my office laptop whenever I want.

I followed the same port-forwarding procedure to configure my router to forward Port 8082 to `192.168.1.2` (TCP, WAN interface is pppoe2). I ran a python/nodejs http server listening on `0.0.0.0:8082`.

If I try to access my newly spun server from public IP I get timeout. This is the problem. *I can SSH into my remote machine, but website hosted on it doesn't work*

### Steps tried:

I take remote desktop of office laptop (using port 5900 for x11 forwarding) and find that firefox can open `localhost:8082`, `127.0.0.1:8082` and `192.168.1.2:8082` properly.

I tried shutting down extra services like *gogs* and *nginx* (which was listening on port 80 even though I didn't tell it to) via systemctl, but still no luck.

Further, `curl http://PUBLIC_IP:8082` gives different outputs:

1. At home, in my Cmder I get `curl: (7) Failed to connect to PUBLIC_IP port 8082: Timed out`
2. However, in SSH terminal (i.e. of remote machine), I get `curl: (7) Failed to connect to PUBLIC_IP port 8082: Connection refused`

Why is connection refused?

Thanks to @davidgo, I tried

```
$ sudo tcpdump -vv -i enp7s0 | grep 8082
tcpdump: listening on enp7s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
```

If I curl `localhost:8082` or `192.168.1.2:8082` I see 200 on server logs but I don't see any output in the above command.
But if I curl `PUBLIC_IP:8082` from

1. inside SSH session I get

```
    duckDNSsubDomain.40626 > abts-north-dynamic-031.P3.P2.P1.airtelbroadband.in.8082: Flags [S], cksum 0x469a (incorrect -> 0x84f5), seq 18095393, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2474578357 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    abts-north-dynamic-031.P3.P2.P1.airtelbroadband.in.8082 > duckDNSsubDomain.40626: Flags [R.], cksum 0x8cea (correct), seq 0, ack 18095394, win 0, length 0
```

and a quick `connection refused` complain by curl (BTW my public IPv4 looks like `P1.P2.P3.31`.

2. And if I do the same curl from my home computer I see

```
    157.32.251.70.50664 > duckDNSsubDomain.8082: Flags [S], cksum 0x299d (correct), seq 132055921, win 64240, options [mss 1370,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
    157.32.251.70.50664 > duckDNSsubDomain.8082: Flags [S], cksum 0x299d (correct), seq 132055921, win 64240, options [mss 1370,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
    157.32.251.70.50664 > duckDNSsubDomain.8082: Flags [S], cksum 0x299d (correct), seq 132055921, win 64240, options [mss 1370,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
    157.32.251.70.50664 > duckDNSsubDomain.8082: Flags [S], cksum 0x299d (correct), seq 132055921, win 64240, options [mss 1370,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
    157.32.251.70.50664 > duckDNSsubDomain.8082: Flags [S], cksum 0x299d (correct), seq 132055921, win 64240, options [mss 1370,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
```

and curl fails with timeout.

Now I am guessing my ISP doesn't like random ports. So I tried hosting my webserver on port 80. Again, localhost and 192.186.1.2 work as expected **but** `http://PUBLIC_IP:80/` opens up router control panel :(

So I try hosting it on a well-known port that's not 80 or 443. I choose 21 (FTP), use sudo to run webserver listening on `0.0.0.0:21` but firefox/chrome don't let me open it and curl hangs for a while before failing with a timeout.

Comment: If you run tcpdump on your web server and then try and make an external request do you see any traffic to your webserver on port 8082?  If you browse to 192.168.1.2:8082 does the web page come up?

Comment: @davidgo Yes I see the web page when I browse/curl to `192.168.1.2:8082`, checking tcpdump now

Comment: @davidgo tcpdump -i eth0 is giving too much output (perhaps because I am in SSH), any suggestions on how to filter out the needed output?

Comment: try "tcpdump -i eth0 -p 8082"

Comment: What router do you have? Your experience setting up for forwarding is nothing like mine. The routers I've used generally have a web interface that allow you to do it and you don't have to specify SSH commands at all. This has been my experience on routers from Netgear, actiontec, and Linksys, both running factory firmware and with open source tomato firmware.

Comment: Normally I would start with tracert, but you are obviously able to get to the IP address, just not the port.  I googled for "tracert different port" and found this.  It's basically a telnet hack.  https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/articles/227989007-How-to-Running-a-TCP-Traceroute  Maybe it could help you find where the port is being blocked.

Comment: I'll respond with an answer shortly.  Just for future reference, its a good idea to send a comment to "@username"  if you update your question or have a comment relative to that user - otherwise its likely to get missed.  It is sheer luck I actually saw your update!

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I have 777vr1 router. That `ssh -v -t -L ...` command is what I use to SSH into my office laptop from home. You are right, 777vr1 has a web-interface for such settings, I navigate like `Advanced` > `NAT` > `Virtual Server`

Comment: Then I'm not sure why you are using the `-L` option for SSH.   With port forwarding you should just be able to ssh directly to your external IP address (or host name).

Answer (score 1):

The evidence strongly suggest the problem is not with your router, rather it is with the setup of your web server.    I strongly suspect that you have firewall rules on your webserver which are dropping traffic to port 8082.   To check if this is the issue, issue the command -

```
 /sbin/iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8082 -j ACCEPT
```

If things start working as a result you know its a firewall issue, and you would then need to work out how the firewall is invoked and modify this behaviour (which is distro dependent)

The reason you are getting 200's when executed from that machine without it appearing in the tcpdump command is that the command I provided only looks for traffic on the ethernet interface - and traffic from that machine does not traverse that interface.

Comment: That command didn't give any output

Comment: Still getting connection refused from curl and firefox (inside x11 remote desktop) saying  server too busy